# selecting distinct rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to select distinct but its not working

```
SELECT  Distinct `table1`.`myID` AS `myID`,  
                 `table1`.`TypeID` AS `TypeID`,
```

Is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: What is not working, what result do you get instead of what you want? I suspect you are trying to use distinct in a way it's not intended. If you are selecting more than one column the resultset will contain the distinct TUPLES (pairs, triplets, etc.) of values, not the distinct values per each column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinct doesn't work on a single field, it works on the entire row. Your result contains only the distinct rows, i.e. only rows where all fields are the same are removed.

If you want distinct values for a specific field, you can use `group by`:

```
select table1.myID, min(table1.TypeID) as TypeId
from ...
group by table1.myID
```

This will give you a result with distinct values for `myID`, but for the fields that you are not grouping on you should specify which value to get. For this you use aggregates like `min` and `max`. MySQL might allow you specify fields without aggregates, but then it will just pick the first value that comes up (which might not at all be what you think would be the first value).

Comment: what do I do for single record do u know?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you seem to want is:

```
SELECT  Distinct 'myID' as IDType, `table1`.`myID` AS ID
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'TypeID' as IDType, `table1`.`TypeID` AS `ID`
```

This will give you unique values for each column as follows:

```
myID    1
myID    2
myID    3
TypeID  101
TypeID  201
TypeID  301
```

You won't know which values go together, but you will know which values show up in each column.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use distinct on a column only rows.

You can accomplish what you are trying to do by using subquery.